# centos - comparing multiple decimal numbers (versions)

Tags: centos, rpm

So I'm trying to think of a way to do the following

I have the following sample data.

"0.86-6.el6" vs "0.86-6.el6_4"   > VALUE1 is less than value2"
"2.6.32-754.9.1.el6" vs 2.6.32-754.15.3.el6  > VALUE1 is less than value2"

These are centos package version.  So i'm trying to figure out how the packages itself can be compared. Basically find out if the package installed is greater than the package available in the repo?

thanks

Comment: You could use sort command to arrange your version, then you could use head to print out the latest order. sort -nr <file with package version> | head -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ rpmdev-vercmp 0.86-6.el6 0.86-6.el6_4
0.86-6.el6 < 0.86-6.el6_4
```